# Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Ao tentar executar o código abaixo

```
fetch(`https://mktp.oversystem.com.br:8443/MKTPlace2/rest/sinistrosZurich`, {
      method: "GET",
      header: {
        "Access-token": "aC0009E000081007F400dF210",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Erro: ", err);
  });
```

Ou até mesmo um código mais simples, como o de baixo, só para testar se meu node está executando um micro serviço.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const url='https://httpbin.org/get'
fetch(url).then((res)=>{
  console.log(res)
})
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao executar o comando `node app.js` no PowerShell

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m]
```

Sabem me dizer o que pode estar de errado?

Já desinstalei o Node.js e instalei novamente
Já criei alguma variáveis de ambientes

NODE_ENV = development
NODE_PATH = C:\node_modules

Não sei também se as variáveis de ambiente estão corretas...

Comment: Pode ser o encoding do seu arquivo **app.js**, verifique qual é e tente salvar como **UTF-8** para ver se funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para variáveis de ambiente, o = deve ficar grudado com as palavras:

NODE_ENV=development&& NODE_PATH=C:\node_modules

mas não sei se é esse o motivo do erro.
os códigos isolados estão ok, testei ambos aqui.

o erro está em alguma outra parte que você não mostrou aqui.